# Detox tests hang and reloads app several times before running tests, how to debug?

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, detox

I am trying to debug an issue where my app takes around 20 seconds to run a single test. The timeline looks like:

- Run `detox test`
- List item
- App launches
- ...5 seconds later, app refreshes
- ...5 seconds later, app refreshes
- ...5 seconds later, Tests run, and pass

I tried a fresh RN app and it seemed to work without this issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on how to find the issue.

Comment: Post your test code. Post verbose logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with this issue I discovered the problem by running Lower-level resource debugging (https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md#lower-level-idling-resources-debug-ios-only)

This alerted me to the fact there was a continuous animation occurring, specifically a `<ActivityIndicator />` on a screen that was hidden but still causing detox to hang. Removing the `<ActivityIndicator />` fixed the issue with the delay.

Comment: Also check the mocking docs to see how to remove the indicator only for testing.

Comment: @LeoNatan do you mean the React Native docs? I only see an option `hidesWhenStopped`. Is that what you mean?